# Can't connect to mongodb instance running on docker-machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-machine

I'm fairly new to docker and I'm trying to connect from my machine to a mongo server running on a docker-machine.

I started the docker image as it is documented in the [official mongo repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/):

`docker run --name my-mongo -d mongo`

Because I'm running on a docker-machine I'm using the machine ip (got it with `docker-machine ip dev`) and default mongo port and type:

`mongo --host 192.168.99.100 --port 27017`

And I'm getting this response:

```
2015-09-28T17:20:14.438+0300 warning: Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-09-28T17:20:14.439+0300 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.99.100:27017 (192.168.99.100), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

From the logs I can see that mongo started off just fine:

```
2015-09-28T14:12:47.550+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp
2015-09-28T14:12:47.551+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
2015-09-28T14:12:47.554+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

What am I missing - is it my configuration or the way I'm trying to start the mongo shell (I also tried to connect with node application - no success either).

Comment: Use the -p option to expose a port on the host machine. Try: "docker run ... -p 27017:27017 ... mongo"

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP could be ping from your system. if so

Have done port forwarding in Dockerfile

You have to map the docker port which runs the mongo DB to a system port and need to connect to that port if you are not connecting from the local system

Comment: What do you mean by port forwarding? If by using the "-p" so I've used that as well. The ping to the machine is indeed not working as well. I'm using docker client 1.8

Comment: Can you please let me know the ip address of your machine and the ip address of the docker container running the mongo DB. just need to check they are in the same network.

Comment: might need to configure NAT